# Node Allocation on kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am managing a Kubernetes cluster with 10 nodes(On-prem) and the node's configuration is not identical, 5 nodes are of 64 cores and 125G ram, and 5 nodes are of 64 cores and 256G ram.
Most of the time I keep getting alerts saying the node CPU/MEMORY is high and I see the pods are getting restarted, as it is consuming 92-95% of CPU and memory on certain nodes, I want to apply CPU and Memory Allocation on nodes so that the CPU utilization doesn't go very high.

I tried manually editing the node configuration but that did not work.

Any leads for this will be helpful!

Comment: Something like https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes-using-node-affinity/ might be helpful to affine certain high resource eater pods on nodes with higher resources.

Comment: can't I add update the node configuration? let us suppose the node has 64 cores and 125G ram, I allow only 80% of resources to be allocated on that node.

Answer (score 1):

In K8s, you can limit the resources usage for the pod containers and reserve a some cpus/memory for the container to avoid this problem:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: <pod name>
spec:
  containers:
  - name: c1
    image: ...
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
  - name: c2
    image: ...
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```

Comment: Hi @Hussein, thank you for your quick response.
I already have this in place, I want to optimize at the node level, any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Set a default limit for each pod or limit the maximum amount of resources visible for your pods?

Comment: I want to set the allocation on the node, total capacity against allocatable resource.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Kubernetes document for setting the node level allocatable resource.

Fixed using the below document
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#node-allocatable
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/